# Method Deactivate and TryClose - Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I would be very grateful if someone explain my "differences" between method Deactivate and TryClose in MVVM framework Caliburn.Micro.

For example my app has this structure:

- Shell (WPF window)

  - SomeScreen (User control) - is active

I know that method is Deactivate is call everytime if is screen deactivated. An method TryClose is  used on attempt to close some screen.

My questions are:

1. I click on X button on WPF window.
   First is call method deactivate on
   SomeScreen object and then is call
   the same method on Shell object ?

   After deactivate method is totally object destroyed? - "remove reference on him"?
2. When I close WPF window which is shell it call wich methods from IConductor ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been changed in a [recent update to Caliburn Micro.](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/33afbdef6dc2)

There's just the Deactivate method now that can optionally take a bool to say whether it is closing or not.